# run.bat command line JVM argument not passed as expected

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm trying to pass run.bat -Djava.messaging.ServerPeerID=1 , but the args '=' been replaced with space. So the arguments passed to Main.java gets set as true for java.messaging.ServerPeerID.... but it shouldn't be . The Main should have got the arg as appropriately.....

Sample piece of code

```
set ARGS =
:loop1
if %1= "" goto contiArg
else (
  # my echo here : echo " Args ... %1"
Set ARGS = %ARGS% %1
 Shift
)
Goto loop1
```

Line my echo line was throwing errorven i used double quotes as u mentioned.....

Comment: `run.bat "-Djava.messaging.ServerPeerID=1"`  ?

Answer (score 0):

`=` is a standard delimiter in batch/cmd.exe so the only way to pass it as argument is to enclose it in double quotes (use `run.bat "-Djava.messaging.ServerPeerID=1"`).
The java should be able to handle the quotes but if you wish you can dequote the argument by using `%~1` when passed to the java.

Answer (score 0):

Please try "%*" in your script, so the parameters are passed in without processing.

See : [batch file to run jar file with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306918/batch-file-to-run-jar-file-with-parameters)

And [Batch : For what is this symbol used? (percent-sign asterisk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913019/batch-for-what-is-this-symbol-used-percent-sign-asterisk)